# la duración de un viaje con java (básico) con respuesta con horas y minutos

Tags: java, bluej

Me estoy introduciendo en la programación y el profesor pide que calculemos la duración de un viaje a través de 4 inputs, hora de llegada y de salida y minutos de llegada y salida.
Él pide que la respuesta sea en minutos, pero no me gusta y quiero que la de en horas y minutos. de momento llevo esto pero creo que no es así-:

```
        double duracionmin;
        double duracion;
        double resto;
        double restomin;

        duracionmin = ((hdl - hds)*60) + mdl - mds;
        duracion = duracionmin / 60;
        resto = duracionmin % 60;
        restomin = resto * 60;
        System.out.println("duracion", "restomin");´´´
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -1):

Hola Nacho Gil veo algunos errores, por ejemplo, veo que imprimes "duracion", "restomin" eso no te va a devolver mas que el literal osea el texto. Por otro lado podrías especificar que valores tiene hdl - hds y mdl - mds ya que en el codigo no se ve esas variables. Un saludo.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. Es un comentario. Mira [consejos sobre cómo usar el sitio: comentar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3761/consejos-sobre-c%c3%b3mo-usar-el-sitio/3765#3765) para más información.